# How to set C# Console Application to use default console settings (Windows Server 2012)?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2017, console-application, windows-server

Created a console application using C#/Visual Studio 2017. When I run the console application from VS or on a Windows 10 machine, it uses the default settings for my console application (Options/Font/Layout/Colors) which is perfect. However when I try to run it on a Test Server using Windows Server 2012 R2, it uses random settings (small buffer size/large font/odd shaped window). I've tried:

- Setting Defaults on Server(2012) to same defaults on Local (Windows 10/VS)
- Programmatically setting features of console window
- Running from Command Line

When I run the application from command line(program.exe), it uses the default settings. But when I click on the executable it does not. What am I missing here?

Comment: The OS remembers console settings by user account and application name.  Cmd.exe and yourapp.exe are not the same.  You can see these settings back with Regedit.exe, HCKU/Console key.  Superuser.com is a good place to ask questions about it.

Comment: Awesome! Did not realize that user and application console windows were within separate settings. Found the entries and set the defaults for the application. They were very much different. Thank you!

Comment: It's not based on the application name, but rather on the initial console window title. If you don't set a window title via `STARTUPINFO` when calling `CreateProcess` (e.g. when using CMD's `start` command), the initial window title is the application path. Also, if a console application is started via a .lnk shortcut, the settings get loaded from and saved to the shortcut instead of the registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there's two different settings for the console. One for the User Account and another for initial console window title(in this case my application). I was able to look at the settings within Regedit.exe, HCKU/Console key and remove the settings for my initial console window title and then ran application (as admin) and changed the defaults there. Thank you for the comments!

Comment: Console initialization first applies the default settings ("HKCU\Console"). The window-title settings ("HKCU\Console\[Window Title]") override the defaults. Instead of using the registry, the default and window-title settings can be set respectively via the "Defaults" and "Properties" dialogs in the GUI.

Comment: When you start an application using a .lnk shortcut, the path to the .lnk file is passed as the window title (i.e. `STARTF_TITLEISLINKNAME` is flagged in the startup info from `GetStartupInfo`). The console API in turn uses the .lnk file for the window-title settings, and the "Properties" dialog modifies the shortcut.